# asp button dentro de um modal nao faz triggering ao click event

Tags: c#, asp.net

Se clicar no botao ele faz-me a verificação das *textbox* , formatos incorrectos etc , mas se as *textbox* estiverem todas validadas ele não chama o evento associado, a ele alguma ideia ?
o botao esta dentro de um *form* com *runat="server"* que herdo da *master page*.

```
<asp:Button ID="subPedido" runat="server" Text="Enviar" OnClick="SubPedido_Click" CssClass="buttonFloatRight"></asp:Button>
```

Funciona se estiver fora do modal

Comment: Pedro, existe o evento click criado no code-behind?

Comment: @AngeloSimonato sim existe sim , aliás se eu substituir o <asp:Button> por um <asp:LinkButton> funciona perfeitamente, contudo ignora-me as verificações das textboxs